# Как правильно сделать запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (
    `FIELD_SERVER_ID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `FIELD_PLAYER` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `FIELD_KIT_NAME` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `FIELD_TIMESTAMP` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Допустим в этой таблице есть запись.

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, 
                              FIELD_PLAYER, 
                              FIELD_KIT_NAME, 
                              FIELD_TIMESTAMP) 
                      VALUES ("server_id", 
                              "name", 
                              "kit", 
                              11111)
```

Как правильно сделать запрос на обновление записи выше? Подобную задачу я ранее решал с помощью `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` но на данный момент у меня нет уникального ключа. Как можно решить данную задачу?

Запись будет обновляться по FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME, а значение, которое будет обновляться FIELD_TIMESTAMP. Проблема в том, что я не знаю заранее, существует ли запись в бд или нет(для её обновления).

Comment: А как, пардон, понять, что надо обновлять некими (какими, кстати?) значениями именно эту запись?

Comment: Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Если запись будет обновляться по тем 3м полям, то в БД должна быть заведомо только одна запись с одним набором этих полей. Но тогда эти 3 поля и составляют уникальный ключ, просто создайте такой ключ из этих 3х полей и используйте как обычно `on duplicate`

Comment: Нет, записей с теми 3 полями может быть больше, так как серверов много (от сюда разные идентификаторы) + много китов и уже уникальность не получается, так как на разных серверах кит будет называться так же как и на другом.

Comment: Вы не поняли, я предлагаю сделать не каждое отдельное поле уникальным, а создать уникальный индекс из 3х полей `create unique index index_name on TABLE_KITS_LOG(FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME)` уникальным будет именно набор полей, скажем (1,1,'name1') и при этом может существовать немного другой набор (1,2,'name1')

Comment: *и уже уникальность не получается* Непонятно. Если указанная совокупность полей НЕ уникальна - при решении поставленной задачи обновятся ВСЕ записи-дубликаты по этой совокупности полей.

Comment: Я сейчас покажу пример как это будет в таблице. Ожидайте

Comment: http://joxi.ru/nAy8G71uYzQO42 - таблица. Данная таблица описывает ситуация для 2х серверов. К примеру игрок с ником name взял все киты на сервере rpg и classic, от этого в бд появились соответствующие записи, которые так и говорят, что игрок 'name' взял кит с название 'kit' на сервер 'server_id' в 'time'. Я же в свою очередь буду должен обновить соответствующую запись в момент, когда игрок возьмёт кит.

Comment: @Prototype-TV У вас связка из 3х полей уникальна. такой индекс как я сказал выше вы можете спокойно создать. заодно он не позволит вставить в ту таблицу вторую запись с полями ('roo','name','mods'), а запись с полями ('roo','name','mods25') позволит вставить, ибо набор полей другой

Comment: Окей. Давайте тогда я попробую разобраться в вашей идеи. Вы можете  написать ответ в теме, где покажите как именно вы хотите сделать связку с индексами и как их правильно использовать. Про индексы я конечно слышал, но мне не нужно было ими пользоваться. Мой уровень знаний в SQL как говорится 'SELECT'. )

Comment: Вы просто дайте тот create index, который я написал выше (только имя индексу получше задайте) и все. пользоваться индексом как то специально не надо. все работает автоматически. просто пишите как раньше, `insert ... on duplicate key update`. Он сработает на update только в случае если найдет запись с точно такими же всеми 3мя полями. С тем же успехом вы можете создавать не индекс, а при создании таблицы объявить первичный ключ, но не как обычно состоящий из одного поля (id), а так же из 3х полей (в скобках, через запятую)

Comment: А, ну я походу понял суть. Пойду в MySQL Workbench тестировать. Спасибо.

Comment: А ещё - если обновление заключается только в изменении штампа времени на **текущий**, лучше определить поле как `FIELD_TIMESTAMP INT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и вообще исключить его из списка полей вставки/обновления.

Comment: Да, хорошее замечание, спрошу у администрации если на хостах, где стоят сервера одинаковое время с хостом, где сайт и базы, то сделаю так. Прост ещё есть сомнения по по поводу точного времени, ибо с сервера запросы будут отправляться из общей очереди, а там же не только обновление китов, а и ещё кучу запросов.

Answer (score 1):

В описанных условиях решение одним запросом невозможно - все версии запросов с двойным типом действия (REPLACE, INSERT .. ODKU) требуют наличия уникального индекса.

Я бы решил задачу безусловным удалением записи и последующей вставкой новой записи. Т.е.

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE_KITS_LOG` 
WHERE (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) 
   IN ("server_id",     "name",       "kit");

INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, 
                              FIELD_PLAYER, 
                              FIELD_KIT_NAME, 
                              FIELD_TIMESTAMP) 
                      VALUES ("server_id", 
                              "name", 
                              "kit", 
                              2222);
```

Comment: Не плохое решение, вот только один момент. Что будет, если попытаться удалить запись, которая не существует?

Comment: А ничего не будет. В т.ч. ошибки тоже не будет. Просто `0 rows affected`.

Comment: Супер, последний вопрос и помечаю вопрос как лучший. Я что-то смотрю не там или запрос DELETE не правильно написан? (или я уже забыл, сейчас проверю пойду).

Comment: DELETE правильный. Можете переписать на отдельные сравнения для каждого из полей - не влияет. Только знайте - удаление будет медленным - фуллскан же. Лучше прислушаться к совету @Mike выше.