# Правильный запрос

Tags: mysql

Продолжение данной [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760355/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81?noredirect=1#comment1178033_760355)!
Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (
`FIELD_SERVER_ID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`FIELD_PLAYER` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`FIELD_KIT_NAME` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`FIELD_TIMESTAMP` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Для неё есть индекс:

```
CREATE unique index TABLE_KITS_LOG_INDEX on TABLE_KITS_LOG(
FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME);
```

К примеру в таблице есть след записи:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("rpg", "name", "deluxe");
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("rpg", "name", "mods");
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("rpg", "name", "vip");
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("classic", "name", "deluxe");
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("classic", "name", "mods");
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME) VALUES ("classic", "name", "vip");
```

Так как изменение требует только поле `FIELD_TIMESTAMP` я пытаюсь сделать запрос, который с помощью уникального индекса и настройки таблицы сам обновит это поле, ибо при создании таблице я указываю `default` значение и значение при обновление `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Так как я указал, что при обновлении записи колонка  `FIELD_TIMESTAMP` должна сама обновится, то я не знаю что писать после `KEY UPDATE`, в варианте который ниже пишется ошибка: `Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. Нужно учесть, что если записи нет, то её нужно вставить, а если есть - обновить время.

Попытка сделать нужный запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME, FIELD_TIMESTAMP) VALUES ("rpg", "name", "mods")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIELD_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

@Akina help

Comment: Ну типа `INSERT INTO table_kits_log (field_server_id, field_player, field_kit_name) VALUES ("rpg", "name", "mods")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_kit_name=VALUES(field_kit_name);`

Comment: Эм, вчера же был разговор, что уникальность формируется с помощью индекса. Для чего в данном случае указывается `field_kit_name=VALUES(field_kit_name)` ?

Comment: Ваш запрос ничего не делает. Просто нет эффекта (без ошибок).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам необходимо полностью сформировать insert, указав все значения. А в update, действительно, нужно указать только поля, не входящие в уникальный ключ

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_KITS_LOG` 
    (FIELD_SERVER_ID, FIELD_PLAYER, FIELD_KIT_NAME, FIELD_TIMESTAMP) VALUES 
    ("rpg", "name", "mods",  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIELD_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

запрос обнаружит что поле с набором составляющих уникальный ключ существует и в этом случае поменяет timestap. Но запросу надо дать все значения, на случай если такого поля нет. Тем более, что эти значения могут быть разные. Классический вариант - счетчик `INSERT INTO table (id, count) ($id, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count+1`

Comment: Спасибо, запрос работает, только вопросы:
1) Для чего же я тогда при создании писал UPDATE для поля с `FIELD_TIMESTAMP`.
2) Программа(MySQL Workbench), в которой я проверяю это всё дело после выполнения вашего запроса сказала, что было затронуто 2 rows, но по сути запись изменилась в 1 месте и там где нужно, но тогда почему написано, что затронуто 2 строки?

Comment: запрос обнаружит что поле с набором составляющих уникальный ключ существует и в этом случае поменяет timestap. Но запросу надо дать все значения, на случай если такого поля нет. Эти знаяения могут быть разные

Comment: про 2 не могу даже вообразить ситуацию. Правда я и эту прогу в глаза не видел.

Comment: Пойду попробую в обычном MyPhPAdmin сделать, отпишусь о результате. Просто есть подозрение, что 2-ы сетит timestamp.

Comment: Поверил, так же 2 надевает. http://joxi.ru/5mdMLw9ukznd72
Странно как-то это.

Comment: а данные? введите что-то совершенно отличное, 1 например, и потом посмотрите, сколько таких строк. Я, правда, никогда количество строк после подобных запросов не спрашивал

Comment: *вопросы: 1) Для чего же я тогда при создании писал UPDATE для поля с FIELD_TIMESTAMP.* Ну так уберите FIELD_TIMESTAMP из UPDATE и соответственно CURRENT_TIMESTAMP из VALUES. Но оставьте их в ODKU.